# Написать рекурсивную процедуру, которая печатает элементы из всех листьев дерева

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
program exp;

uses crt;

Type
  PTree = ^TTree;
  TTree = Record
    Data : Integer;
    Left, Right : PTree;
  end;

var
  Tree : PTree;
  f1 :text;
  i, sum, y1 : integer;

Procedure InsTree(var ANode : PTree; n : integer);
Begin
  if ANode = nil then
  Begin
    new(ANode);
    With ANode^ do
    Begin
      Left := nil;
      Right := nil;
      Data := n;
    end;
  end
  else if n< ANode^.Data then
    InsTree(ANode^.Left, n) 
  else InsTree(ANode^.Right, n);
End;

Procedure PrintList(ANode : PTree);
Begin
  if ANode <> nil then
  Begin
    if (ANode^.Left=nil) and (ANode^.Right=nil) then
      write(' ', ANode^.Data);
    PrintList(ANode^.Left);
    PrintList(ANode^.Right);
  End;
End;

begin
  clrScr;
  assign(f1,'t1.txt');
  reset(f1);
  while not eof(f1) do
  begin
    readln(f1,i);
    InsTree(Tree, i);
  end;
  writeln('Листья дерева');
  PrintList(Tree);
  close(f1);
end.
```

не выводит почему-то листья, я так забил голову себе что не могу разобраться в простом. Кто сможет, помогите

Comment: Код отформатируйте . Где лесенка? Читать невозможно.

Comment: Я голосую против данного вопроса, т.к. он не отражает стремления разобраться

Comment: По-моему, вам надо разобраться с тем, что там у вас в файле... Вот пример с явно прошитыми данными - работает вроде бы: http://ideone.com/tXAAce

Comment: @4per спасибо за помощь , вы были очень полезны!

Comment: @iluxa1810 отформатировал.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в процедуре 'PrintList'. Из-за условия

> `if (ANode^.Left=nil) and (ANode^.Right=nil) then`

Будут выводиться только последние листья. Должно быть так

```
procedure PrintList(ANode : PTree);
begin
  if ANode <> nil then
  begin
    PrintList(ANode^.Left);
    Write(' ', ANode^.Data);
    PrintList(ANode^.Right);
  end;
end;
```

**UPDATE**

Перед циклом неплохо было бы явно проинициалицировать переменную `Tree`

```
reset(f1);
Tree = nil;
while not eof(f1) do
```

Ну и конечно же выделенную память нужно освобождать. На каждый вызов `New()` должен быть вызов `Dispose()`

```
procedure DestroyTree(ANode: PTree);
begin
  if ANode <> nil then begin
    DestroyTree(ANode^.Left);
    DestroyTree(ANode^.Right);
    Dispose(ANode);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ему и надо вывести листья; вы же выводите **всё**.

Comment: @Harry Читайте название темы "Написать рекурсивную процедуру, которая печатает элементы из **всех** листьев дерева"

Comment: @Harry но оно почему-то, не выводит вообще числа...  почему?

Comment: @Индентикон и мой пример не выводит?

Comment: А что вы вводите? По-моему, у вас проблема не в выводе, а в построении дерева.